# Regex to match two simple cases in a file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Beethoven's Ode to Joy
    667887654456655 667887654456544 556456764 5676545 1 667887654456544

Chrono Trigger - 600AD
    (67 83456 654345 4 3456 7/4 8/6 5/3 
    6783456 654345 4 3456 7/4 8/6 8/6)

FF Prelude
    1235 (1235 8 5321) 532
    [678]3 678(3 6 3)876 31[7]
    1235 (1235 8 5321) 532
    [678]3 678(3 6 3)876 31[7]
    [68]45 68(45 6 54)86 541
    [7]2 567(2 567652)7652
    1235 (1235 8 5321) 53~[1/3/5/8]
```

It's a list of notes for songs to be played by instruments within a game, Guild Wars 2.

I'm trying to create an application to store/read these notes in a nicer format than a thousand-line text file. I'm struggling with the Regex to match these song titles, and the songs themselves.
Song titles need to be able to have any text (just in case).
While the Full list of characters for the songs would be:

```
0-9[](). ~/
```

Thanks

Comment: on the bad side ... you didn't even show what you've tried ... you just asked for help ... on the bright side ... this might be last bad question i see this year ...

Comment: This is not the regex writing service. What effort have you made to do this yourself? If you're *struggling*, you should have at least a few of those efforts you've made to include in your post, right? *Plz give me teh codez* questions don't usually fare well here.

Comment: I apologise if I've made it seem like I view this website as a code-writing service, I was trying to keep it concise and filling up space with badly written, broken regex that i've written didn't seem like a good use of the question.

Comment: @Pikls, Actually no. *It is good* for the question to include your *badly written* code that you've tried. I suggest you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Or have a look at [this checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) which is a good reference for you to make your upcoming questions look better, so you can get help faster, and avoid receiving down votes. Welcome to StackOverflow after all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for the title with `(?<Title>\S[^\n]+)\n` which means match a line starting with something that is not an space, then match everything up until it finds a `\n`.

Then from there look for the code `(?<Code>\s{4}[\S\s]*?(?:(\r?\n){2}|$))` that means four spaces after a title matching everything until it finds a double line break or the end of the file.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(sampleText,
    @"(?<Title>\S[^\n]+)\n(?<Code>\s{4}[\S\s]*?(?:(\r?\n){2}|$))");
```

You can then iterate on matches using

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var title = match.Groups["Title"].Value;
    var code = match.Groups["Code"].Value;
    // trim, etc...
}
```

[image: matches]

See about [Regex Matching groups on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm using [named matched subexpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#named_matched_subexpression) in this example.

For the full regex explanation see [Regex101/f5HaSx](https://regex101.com/r/f5HaSx/1) example I created.

```
/(?<Title>\S[^\n]+)\n(?<Code>\s{4}[\S\s]*?(?:(\r?\n){2}|$))/g
```

- Named Capture Group Title `(?<Title>\S[^\n]+)`

  - `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f ]`)
  - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\n]+`
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
- `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
- Named Capture Group Code `(?<Code>\s{4}[\S\s]*?(?:(\r?\n){2}|$))`

  - `\s{4}` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - `{4}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
  - Match a single character present in the list below `[\S\s]*?`
  - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  - `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f ]`)
  - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - Non-capturing group `(?:(\r?\n){2}|$)`
  - 1st Alternative `(\r?\n){2}`

    - 3rd Capturing Group `(\r?\n){2}`
    - `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
    - A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
    - `\r?` matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
    - `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
  - 2nd Alternative `$`

    - `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)